# SQL Server precision and scale of numeric fields in sqlalchemy/python query

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sql server numeric(10,2) field in a table. An example record has de value 25.00 saved in de database.
When I execute a Sqlalchemy query in a Python script, it always returns the value 2500, no matter I define the field as float or numeric in the table class of the model script.

The example value as seen with SSMS:

[image]

The field as defined in the table class (models.py script):

```
percentualExecucao       = db.Column(db.Float)
```

The result of a Sqlalchemy query (a print of the field and its type):

> `***  2500.0 <class 'float'>`

If I change de column type to:

```
percentualExecucao       = db.Column(db.Numeric)
```

I have this:

> ***  2500 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>

What am I missing here?

Comment: The [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) datatypes are very different. Float is an approximate datatype where numeric is precise.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: `float` *can* be precise, but only when dealing with integer values,but once you start dealing with large numbers you lose accuracy (when depends on the size of the `float`). A number like `12345678901234500` can be stored accurately in a `float(53)`, as the last 2 digits are `0`, but `12345678901234567` ends up being returned as `12345678901234568` when stored as a `float(53)`. The same number as a `float(24)` ends up being `12345678407663616` when converted back to a decimal value.

Comment: @Gord Thompson
Yes, on Windows

Comment: @Larnu The accuracy of `float` has nothing to do with integers vs non-integer numbers, and everything to do with whether the number can be fully represented in a given amount of `base2` digits. So `0.25` will be perfectly accurate, as it's `2^-2` and  large integers can be inaccurate, as you have show. Incidently , the reason `float` is considered imprecise on SQL Server is not because of this (ultimately the final rounded value is an exact value) but because SQL Server runs on different hardware, each of which deal with `float` slightly differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue. With my Windows "Region" format set to "Portugese (Brazil)"

[image: Regional format]

and using the ancient "SQL Server" ODBC driver, I get

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="scott",
    password="tiger^5HHH",
    host="192.168.0.199",
    database="test",
    query = {
        "driver": "SQL Server",
        "regional": "yes",
    }
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo")
    conn.exec_driver_sql("CREATE TABLE foo (n numeric(10,2))")
    conn.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO foo (n) VALUES (25)")

tbl_foo = sa.Table("foo", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    n = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl_foo.c.n)).scalar()
    print(n)  # 2500
    print(type(n))  # <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

If I change "regional" to "no" then I get the correct result

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    n = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl_foo.c.n)).scalar()
    print(n)  # 25.00
    print(type(n))  # <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Note that this is not a bug in SQLAlchemy. I get the same results with plain pyodbc:

```py
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver=SQL Server;"
    "UID=scott;PWD=tiger^5HHH;"
    "Server=192.168.0.199;"
    "Database=test;"
    "regional=yes;"
)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

crsr.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo")
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE foo (n numeric(10,2))")
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO foo (n) VALUES (25)")

n = crsr.execute("SELECT n FROM foo").fetchval()
print(n)  # 2500
print(type(n))  # <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

In fact, this seems to be a known issue with pyodbc

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/753

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and energy in this issue. Using regional = no does not seems to work, but reading your github reference, I've found the pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator('.') option that was de solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

With the kind help of @Gord Thompson, the problem was solved using

```
pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator('.')
```

as suggested in,

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/753